# Title link doesn't change after the content type has been changed

Tags: views

The title link for a view block doesn't change after the content type has been changed.

Title "Video" links to http://example.com/video.

> [image]
>
> [image]

After changing the title to "Entertainment" and the content type to "Entertainment", the "video" title has changed to "Entertainment" but the link still link to http://example.com/video.

Comment: For title, try putting `<a href="/entertainment">Entertainment</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

> For title, try putting `<a href="/entertainment">Entertainment</a>`
>
> Thanks @No Sssweat.